# Ubuntu black screen after update drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

sry for my english

Installed Ubuntu latest version (18), the first time I installed it without connecting to the network, noticeable lag graphics shell (especially noticeable when watching video, video card I have GTX 1050 Ti). Execute the command
`lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D|Display'`

result

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti] (rev a1)    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti]
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
```

Decided to upgrade the drivers, as it is written here

> https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82_nvidia

after reboot system i get black screen, even the grub is not shown, the expectation that will pass by itself, too, did not work. Reinstalled system, only this time was connected to a network, after installation again get the black screen (probably, at once downloaded actual drivers ). How i can to fix ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly an expert but **in Ubuntu 16.04** when I had driver problems I was able to type:
`Cntrl-Alt` and `f1`  or `f2`  (or similar... try the other 'f's on your keyboard) and get a terminal or command prompt.   Then, at the prompt, the older version had a command "sudo systemctl start lightdm.service" that allowed the GUI/graphical interface to work.  ***Perhaps systemctl and lightdm are still used in Ubuntu 18***?

I hope that helps or leads to a solution.  Good luck.

Comment: it didnt work for me(((